# How can I make posole "pop" faster?

Tags: corn, stews, hominy

I have run into this a few times.   I soak dry posole overnight, and then add it to my sweated/sauteed vegetables, add water, and stir it regularly, and it still takes over 4 hours for the kernels to pop.   Is there a part of the process I am missing or doing wrong, or could I just be dealing with old posole?

[Posole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posole) is essentially [Nixtamalized Corn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nixtamalization), or hominy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a pressure cooker.
Try for example this recipe:

http://ljcny.wordpress.com/2011/09/13/chicken-pozole/

where dried hominy is cooked in a pressure cooker.

Comment: No, but only because I don't have one.   I don't really use recipes for this sort of cooking, though, to me it's more about technique and getting a good balance of the various flavors.

Comment: It seems to me that the cooking time with a pressure cooker is greatly reduced due to the higher temperature. If I remember correctly the cooking time is around an hour.

Comment: Here is an example of a Posole recipe which uses a pressure cooker. The cooking time is 1 hour. http://peggyunderpressure.com/2011/05/mexican-pork-posole/

Comment: That appears to use canned hominy rather than dried posole corn, though.

Comment: True. This guy uses dried: http://ljcny.wordpress.com/2011/09/13/chicken-pozole/

Comment: sounds good.   Change the form of your answer from a question, and I'll feel comfortable upvoting it.

Comment: @baka - Done! -

Comment: As per SE policy, the contents of that link should be moved into the body of the answer, in case the link in question dies.

Answer (score 1):

The pop is a steam explosion, caused by rapid heating of the kernels' interiors.

Put the well-soaked kernels into boiling water, only enough at a time to avoid taking the pot off the boil. Add them carefully and watch them pop.

A pressure cookers heat is too gradual and heats the kernels relatively evenly.

Answer (score 0):

10 minutes in pressure cooker from the time it starts to boil, according to a table I found on cooking grains in a pressure cooker